# Negative list index in python

Tags: python

Python noob here. Given an index i in a list, is there any built-in way to find it's negative index. Currently I'm using:

```
neg_index = i - len(list)
```

Comment: what do you mean by "negative index"? its position from the end of the  list?

Comment: I got it .. yes, you are doing it the right way already .. so there's actually no question here :)

Comment: why would you want to do this?...

Answer (score 4):

The solution proposed by you can be derived directly from the definition of negative index: python implicitly add `len(list)` to passed negative index. So, it's fine.

But it's a bit strange that you need to find negative index. I think this task is not tipical.

Comment: Sometimes, it's easier to work from the end of the list to the front of it.  *Sometimes.*

Comment: if you wan't to do that, you may want to look into using the built in [reversed](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reversed) function.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is correct, there is no better way to do that.

Comment: How is this a helpful or different answer? There are at least 2 comments already stating this nearly 10 minutes before your post ..

Comment: @Levon: There was only one answer, even a little unclear to newbies in my opinion. I suggest you should ask people who posted the comments you are referring to, to re-post them as answers. Otherwise, despite the fact they are somewhere on this page, they are not as useful to anyone visiting the site. To sum up: ask them to post their comments as answers, do not prevent people from posting answers, unless they are violating the rules. One other note: I did not read comments before posting the answer, so probably big part of visitors didn't either.

Comment: You are completely right. I don't know why people keep on posting answers as comments; no one has a benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't like the way it looks to do that, you can make a function to do it for you.

if you don't know much about functions, you can find a tutorial on them [here](http://www.penzilla.net/tutorials/python/functions/)

```
def negIndex(array, index):
    return index - len(array)
```

then you could use it like this

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]
index=2
print index #2
print array[index] #3

newIndex = negIndex(array, index)
print newIndex #-3
print array[newIndex] #3
```

or if you wan't to be more technical, you can make a class with this function as an attribute.
in this example, we inherit of the class 'list', so negIndexClass has everything that the list class has, plus a negIndex function

```
class negIndexClass(list):
    def negIndex(self, index):
        return index - len(self)
```

so this would be used like this:

```
array = negIndexClass( [1,2,3,4,5] )
index=2
print index #2
print array[index] #3

newIndex = array.negIndex(index)
print newIndex #-3
print array[newIndex] #3
```